# How to query rewards data from a block

Tags: mining-reward

I am trying to find out how much BTC has been mined over time hence I would like to query the rewards associated with a block. However, I cant seem to find the API endpoint from the BTC databases I searched.

Ideally, it will be something like www.blockchain.com, where we can see all the block data, including the rewards data.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fully downloaded blockchain in your local machine, you can parse the raw database with [this](https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser) script.

Then you can find in output text files transactions with `TX from hash` equal to 64 zeros, there is the coinbase transactions.

Each of this TX has outputs with `Value` fields. The sum of this Values is the mining reward that you trying to find.